# What is the correct way to reassign a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

Should I;

```
a = range(100)
old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)
a = range(200)
old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)
```

or:

```
a = range(100)
old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)
a[:] = range(200)
old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)
```

And more importantly, does it matter? In the first, are the elements in a freed, is their reference count 0? Or do the program still need the references to it. If so, I'm completely overwriting the references in the second example.

Comment: How would "old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)" work if old_list is not defined?

Comment: `a[:] = range(200)` changes the contents of the same list (assuming Python 2 where `range` returns a list) bound to `a` but does *not* rebind `a` to a new list/object. If this "matters" depends on what else uses `a` (and more importantly, the object that was previously bound) and what the behavior is expected to be. (Without other requirements I use the first form and avoid accidental side-effects.)

Comment: I'd like to add that I really don't know what you want to do, can you provide an example of input / output? (replacing 100 by 3 and 200 by 6)

Comment: Yes, it is Python 2. Let's assume old_list is defined. It's a reassignment question perfectly answered below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both ways are valid. There is a subtle difference between them:

- The first creates a completely new list object `a`.
- The second replaces all elements in the existing list object `a`.

The following two snippets demonstrate the difference:

```
# #1
a = range(3)
b = a
a = range(5)
print b

# #2
a = range(3)
b = a
a[:] = range(5)
print b
```

The first prints out

```
[0, 1, 2]
```

whereas the second prints out

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

As per i am getting your question this seems to help
for 1st problem:-

```
old_list = tuple(range(110))
a = range(100)
old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)
print id(a)
a = range(200)
old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)
print id(a)
```

output is:-

```
140412939507040
140412939380568
```

for 2nd problem:-

```
a = range(100)
old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)
print id(a)
a[:] = range(200)
old_list = filter(lambda x: x not in a, old_list)
print id(a)
```

output is :-

```
140295816890632
140295816890632
```

1st time `id` is freed but 2nd time it remain same.
In 2nd problem you are just coping the data into the indexes of a.

Comment: So what is fastest, copying the data into the indexes as in (2), or creating the new list as in (1) ?

Comment: Don't even think about "what is fastest" at this stage. Both are reasonable, and therefore reasonably efficient ways to do it. Any performance differences (if they exist) are besides the point.

Comment: @Martol1ni : For this situation, (1) is the cleanest code. Actual speed differences would be tiny, and depend on implementation details. I think you'd enjoy reading [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) by SO member, Ned Batchelder.